# Using Postman (or cUrl) to connect to Mobile Service (Azure)

Tags: curl, access-token, azure-mobile-services, postman

I've created a standard Azure Mobile Service and followed [Add authentication to your Mobile Services app](http://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/).

Registered Google for identity and got the login to work and I'm getting a token, something like this:

```
{
"user":{"UserId":"Google:123123123"},
"authenticationToken":"[token]"}
}
```

Now I want to use Postman or cUrl to run a REST call to the Mobile Service but I'm at a loss how to add the token to the request.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question, and accept it, as it will help others with the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the book 'Windows Azure Mobile Services' in more detail, I added the Header 'X-ZUMO-AUTH' with the authenticationToken I received from Google.

The Rest call is now authenticated as a User with the UserId I received from Google.

Comment: Can you share if the token you added was something like:
`code`newRequest.Headers.Add("x-zumo-auth", "ya29.1AFFjN6_yw7B0UUXHHU5J0FdsJbllVt_xcDuXlZ9yYzd--XSWjMgciDMt3OMSvs0g0qu");

Comment: @MrinalSaurabh to be honest I've abandoned the above code base and rewrote the authentication stuff in my API using this great blog post:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

Comment: This post seriously looks great. Thanks man! I am assuming that means you are not using Azure PaaS authentication provided on the mobile services any more? I'm having a nightmare consuming Pubilc(authenticated) api app in a .Net application.

Comment: @MrinalSaurabh You assume right I'm not using Azure PaaS authentication. The blog post describes 99% of the code I need to make it work.